# Get xml attributes and values using ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using nokogiri library in ruby to parse a webpage. I am getting the XML result as:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1399140 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1398264 "\n">, 
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1395d50 name="i" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1395cb4 name="class" value="icon-pctgrm p-01_g">,
#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1395ca8 name="title" value="new">]>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1394e20 "\n">]>
```

From this result I need to get the final result as `class:icon-pctgrm p-01_g, title:new`

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

First save the xml as `test.xml` in the same directory of this script and then run this-

```
require 'nokogiri'

File.foreach(File.open("test.xml")) do |line|
  if /Attr/.match(line)
    print line.split('name=')[-1].split('"')[1] + ":" + line.split('value=')[1].split('"')[1] + ", "
  end
end
```

This will give the expected result as- `class:icon-pctgrm p-01_g, title:new,`